# How do I solve $c^2 + 1 > 2c - 1$ when $c \ge 2$?

Tags: solution-verification, quadratics

We have been given a question to do as part of a task set by our lecturer, however he has failed to provide any examples of similar questions with all the corona stuff going on, and I cannot find the name of the method used to solve it. The question is as follows.

> Suppose that $c\in \Bbb N$. Prove that:
> If $c\ge 2$ then $c^2+1>2c−1$.

What is this type of question called, and what would be the working to solve it?

Comment: You probably wnat to prove this by induction

Comment: You can rewrite the inequality as $c^2 > 2(c-1)$. Then it's maybe easier for you to see that this holds when $c \geq 2$.

Answer (score 2):

$$(c-1)^2\geq 0>1\Rightarrow c^2-2c+1> -1\Rightarrow c^2+1>2c-1$$
Now this would be the case for any $c\in N$, thus valid for $c\geq 2$.

(I think you meant some else equation)

Comment: If I were grading your work, I likely would not give you much credit for this answer.  It appears that you have started by assuming the conclusion, from which you derive a true inequality.  Your approach can be made rigorous by clearly indicating which statements are implied by (or imply) others.  It would also help to write the process in the reverse order, so that the conclusion is at the end: $$ (c-1)^2\ge 0 > -1 \implies c^2 - 2c + 1 > -1 \implies c^2 + 1> 2c - 1. $$

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example of when [proof by induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) is useful. The base case is $c=2$. Then assume that the inequality holds for some $k>2$ and show that the inequality holds for $k+1$.

Comment: @Devansh 's answer provides a direct proof which may be preferable